# Unity: Deactivate GameObject on creation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject, disable

I'm creating a GameObject (rectangle with a texture) at runtime while starting my app and want to display it later. But if I set it inactive right away (`myGO.setActive(false)`) or even while it's still creating it (directly after `GameObject o = new GameObject()`), it shows up for a second, then disappears again.

I'm aware that I could create the GameObject the first time it's actually needed but I want to do all the setup like that while displaying a loading screen.

Is it possible to set a GameObject inactive instantly when it's ready but before it's actually displayed?

Code (shortened version):

```
private void StartUpMethod() {
    GameObject myGO = MakePhoto(vertices);

    if(myGO==null) {
        ShowError("Error Message");
    } else {
        myGO.SetActive(false);
    }
}

private GameObject MakePhoto(Vector3[] vertices) {
    byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(2,2);
    tex.LoadImage(fileData);

    GameObject o = new GameObject();
    Mesh m = new Mesh();
    Material mat = new Material(Shader.Find("Standard")) { mainTexture = tex };
    Vector3[] vv = new Vector3[] { new Vector3(0,0,0),new Vector3(length,0,0),new Vector3(length,width,0),new Vector3(0,width,0) };

    if(o.GetComponent<MeshFilter>() == null) { o.AddComponent<MeshFilter>(); }
    if(o.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>() == null) { o.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>(); }
    o.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = m;
    o.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = mat;

    m.vertices = vv;
    m.uv = new Vector2[] {new Vector2(0,0),new Vector2(0,1),new Vector2(1,1),new Vector2(1,0)};
    m.triangles = new int[] { 0,1,2,0,2,3 };
    m.RecalculateBounds();
    m.RecalculateNormals();
    o.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(270,0,0));
    o.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0,0,270));
    o.transform.position = new Vector3(x,z,y);

    return o;
}
```

Comment: you can leave it with renderer disabled or if you are instantiating dynamically, you can disable it before the instantiate method be called.

Comment: @Daniel There's no prefab for it, so no instantiating of that sort is going on. ;) Disabling the renderer worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe also disable the `MeshRenderer`, then re-enable that too?

```
myGO.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
```

Comment: Doing it right before setting the GO inactive seems to be too late, so I put it directly after `o.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = mat;` and now it's not showing up for a second anymore. Thanks!